# How do I convert geojson and shp files to topojson files using gdal?

Tags: python, d3.js, gdal, ogr2ogr

I have successfully installed Python and GDAL with guidance from this link
[Installation instructions](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows)

I've seen some web tools that can convert to and fro the formats I mentioned above. I decided to install ogr2ogr locally. I need some simple instructions to bring up the command tool and convert my files. Most important is the switch to preserve properties or id of the geometries.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GDAL webpage for the GeoJSON driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html), GDAL supports **reading** TopoJSON as of OGR 1.11. It says nothing about **writing** TopoJSON, so I am assuming writing is not supported.

From the [TopoJSON readme](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-server/blob/master/README.md#geo2topo), the binary `geo2topo` will convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON **in-place**. It looks like that is the tool you should be using, not `ogr2ogr`.

The workflow would therefore be as follows:

```
shapefile translated to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr
GeoJSON updated to TopoJSON with geo2topo
```

Comment: Thanks I got it. I now have node.js and npm installed. I tried to run the following command: geo2topo -o myfile.topo.json myfile.geo.json. It results to an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0. I am sure this file is valid and I do not have character ? at position 0.